# Why does my linked list code result in link errors?

Tags: c++

I'm new to linklist, and i'm having a tough time with it. I'm trying to display some values that i've appended to the nodes, But i keep getting linkerror messages. Here is what I have so far.

```
LinkList.h
-


    #ifndef LINKLIST_H
    #define LINKLIST_H

    class LinkList
    {
    private:
        struct ListNode
        {
            int value;
            ListNode *next;
        };

        ListNode *head;

    public:
        LinkList();
        void insertNode(int);

        void deleteNode(int);
        void appendNode(int);
        void display() const;

        //~LinkList();
    };
    #endif


Impl.cpp
-

    #include <iostream>
    #include "LinkList.h"
    using namespace std;

    void LinkList::appendNode(int num)
    {
        ListNode * newNode;
        ListNode * nodePtr;

        newNode = new ListNode;
        newNode->value = num;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if(!head)
        {
            head = newNode;
            head->value = num;
            head->next=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            nodePtr = head;

            while(nodePtr->next!=NULL)
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            newNode = new ListNode;
            newNode->value = num;
            newNode->next = NULL;

            nodePtr->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    void LinkList::display() const
    {
        ListNode *nodePtr;
        nodePtr = head;

        while (nodePtr != NULL)
        {
            cout << nodePtr->value << endl;

            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
    }
```

LinkList::LinkList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

```
main.cpp
-


    #include <iostream>
    #include "LinkList.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        LinkList mine;

        mine.appendNode(6);
        mine.appendNode(9);
        mine.appendNode(11);

        mine.display();

        return 0;
    }
```

I fixed some of the initial problems but the program just crashes when it  runs and i'm not sure why

I'm not sure what the problems is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format the code: Edit the post, select the code, press on the [{}] or [Ctrl]-[K]

Comment: please format your post properly: it's barely readable. Since you're using c++ and STL, is there a reason you cannot not just use std::list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared a LinkList constructor, and a destructor, but you did not define them:

```
LinkList::LinkList() : head(NULL)
{
}

LinkList::~LinkList()
{
    // delete your memory here...
}
```

Comment: The constructor should probably at least initialize the pointers.